# Reading integers for a stack from user input

Tags: java, stack, java.util.scanner

I am trying to create a program that takes user input from a scanner and pushes it onto a stack and then pops off each element and prints it out. Here is my code thus far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class NumberReverse {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter numbers: ");
    int number = sc.nextInt();

    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
    stack.push(number);

    while (!(stack.isEmpty())) {
        System.out.println(stack.pop());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please try to describe the problem and formulate a specific question.

Comment: So far, I only get the first number that was entered.

Comment: You only call `nextInt()` once. You make an array the size of the first int inputted and then iterate over that array entering the inputted number into `stack`.

Comment: It appears you are trying to read in numbers from the user. You are using the number the user enters to instantiate an array of length number, but after that you are not populating the array with any ints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something more like this...

Before you are only reading in one number one time, which seems like you want to be used for the size of your array. After this, you continually push the same number onto the stack because you never prompt the user to enter in any other number.

The code below goes one step further than your code in that once you have learned the number from the User and set your array size, you ask for a new number over and over again to populate your array until your array is filled. This can be accomplished by prompting the user to enter a value over and over again in the for loop.

I am not really sure why exactly you need an array to do what you want to do though, consider removing the array and just using the first number entered as your bounds for the for loop rather than the array size. The array data structure is really just a waste of space as the only time you ever use it is to use its length as a stopping point in the for loop

```
public class NumberReverse {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


      System.out.print("Enter stack size: ");

      int number = sc.nextInt();
      int[] array = new int[number];

      Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
      for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
          System.out.println("Enter your number: ");
          int value = sc.nextInt();              
          stack.push(value);
      }

      while (!(stack.isEmpty())) {
          System.out.println(stack.pop());


      }    
    }
}
```

Based on the comment below consider trying something like the code below. You are only printing out one number for the same reasons that I have listed above...

```
import java.util.*; 
public class NumberReverse { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter how many numbers you want to place on the Stack: ");
        int stackSize = sc.nextInt();
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i < stackSize; i++){ 
            System.out.println("Enter numbers: "); 
            int number = sc.nextInt();  
            stack.push(number); 
        }
        while (!(stack.isEmpty())) { 
            System.out.println(stack.pop()); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over all the numbers entered by the user, and push them on the stack:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter numbers (finish with something else): ");

    final Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();

    while (sc.hasNextInt())
        stack.push(sc.nextInt());

    while (!(stack.isEmpty()))
        System.out.println(stack.pop());
}
```

Comment: Sorry guys, I meant to take out the array. Here is the code I meant to post, which only seems to push the first number you enter onto the stack and pops and prints out that number only, regardless of how many  numbers you enter:

Comment: import java.util.*;

    public class NumberReverse {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.print("Enter numbers: ");
  int number = sc.nextInt();

  Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
  stack.push(number);

  while (!(stack.isEmpty())) {
   System.out.println(stack.pop());
  }
 }
    }

Comment: I have reposted this question. Thanks for all the speedy responses.

Comment: Robert, I have revised my answer with your latest code posted if you feel that your question has been answered, consider accepting an answer!

Comment: Josh, thanks for the help. I accepted your answer. I had to put the out print "Enter your numbers" above the for loop, otherwise the statement prints out the the same number of times as the stackSize.